# PHP - Sort array according another multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array:

```
$row = [
  "serial_number" => "TDZL02616"
  "id_machine" => "1720"
  "action" => "go"
]
```

and I have also an multidimensional array with definition of columns and their order (column 'sequence'):

```
$colDef = [
    [

        'name'       => 'serial_number',
        'sequence'   => 2,
        'visible'    => true,
    ],
    [
        'name'          => 'id_machine',
        'sequence'      => 1,
        'visible'       => true,
    ],
    [
        'name'     => 'action',
        'sequence' => 3,
        'visible'  => true,
    ],
]
```

How can I easily sort the first array (`$row`) according the second array (`$colDef`) and its columns 'sequence' that I will get the result:

```
$row = [
  "id_machine" => "1720"
  "serial_number" => "TDZL02616"
  "action" => "go"
]
```

I have no clue where to start or how to solve it.

Comment: You want $row *keys* in a specific order? Can I ask why? I mean, it won't affect accessing the values..

Comment: I know, that is because I'm using array later in json response to the datatable where data (in tbody) must be in same order as header of table.

Comment: Sounds like a dangerous way of doing it. Can't you send another array along in the JSON, that contains the keys in the right order? Like ['id_machine','serial_number','go']? Edit: Taking it a step further, it should be the responsibility of the client to fetch things in the order needed.

Comment: But that is my question how to change order of keys in right sequence according definition in another array. The process is dynamic so I need at first sort array. The sequence 1. id_machine, 2. serial_number, 3. action doesn't have to be always in that order.

Comment: I understand, and I don't want to cause any trouble at all. I was just trying to highlight some possible dangers in the design :). It's a bit like SELECT * queries in SQL. Unless somehow $colDef is used in both places, then it's of course more safe. ..But in that case, if you have access to $colDef you don't have to order the keys anymore.

Comment: No problem, I get it :-) large datatables in PHP + JS (Vue.js) is quite hard work and among this there are many other problems. But thank you anyway for pointing out some potential issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$colDef2 = [];
foreach($colDef as $cd){
    $colDef2[$cd['sequence']] = $cd['name'];
}
ksort($colDef2);

$row2 = [];
foreach($colDef2 as $i){
    $row2[$i] = $row[$i];
}
```

Note the use of PHP function **ksort** which can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).